# C++ design issue with unordered_set and iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following snippet

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t & seed, const T & v)
{
  std::hash<T> hasher;
  seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
}

const size_t INF(numeric_limits<size_t>::max());

class nodehasher;

class node{

public:
  int x,y;
  unordered_set<node, nodehasher>::iterator neighbs[6];  //Issue Here
  node(){}
  node(int x_, int y_):x(x_),y(y_){}
  void set(int x_, int y_){x = x_,y = y_;}
  bool operator == (const node &n)const{
    return x == n.x && y == n.y;
  }
};

class nodehasher{
  std::size_t operator()(node const& n) const{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    hash_combine(seed, n.x);
    hash_combine(seed, n.y);
    return seed;
  }
};
```

I seem to be having issues declaring the iterators pointing to class node inside node itself.

This causes a huge number of too verbose errors.

Now i realize i could make my neighbs array, an array of pointers to node,
but i want to avoid pointers for obvious reasons

A typical simplified way i use this would be:

```
unordered_set<node, nodehasher> nodes;
void typical_use(node dest){
  auto src_node = node(0,0);
  int neighbcount = 0;
  auto iter = dest.insert(node).first;
  src_node.neighbs[neighb_count] = iter; 
}
```

I could obviously convert it into pointers and do:

```
src_node.neighbs[neighb_count] = &(*iter);
```

But Is there no way to avoid pointers for what i want to do?

**EDIT:**

As many of the comments and answers have pointed out both pointers and iterators to the container elements get invalidated after a rehash
so it is a bad idea storing them.

I was thinking if the following way works instead of an unordered_set of node i will use an unordered_set of pointer to nodes, something like this

```
unordered_set<shared_ptr<node> > nodes;
```

Also, if i know that the number of nodes is always going to be less than 500, i could forgo this whole hash table idea and use an array and each time i will have to search the array to check if the node is already there.

Can you please point out which approach is better?

Comment: I am not sure if it is smart storing iterators in a member variable . I don't know if things internally change after you change the unordered_set and then the iterators would point to something else or be something unexpected.

Comment: @Hayt oh goodness, i didn't even think about that, looks like pointers it is, thank you, should i delete the question?

Comment: If the question does not provide any more value to you you can delete it. You could also try to rephrase/edit the question to where you want to know an alternative to pointers without the iterator-array part.

Comment: Both pointers and iterators can be dangerous if you don't know when the container will invalidate them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Answer (score 2):

Standard containers require complete types for values. `node` isn't complete type at the point where you use it to instantiate `unordered_set<node, nodehasher>`.

You could use [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html#container.main_features.containers_of_incomplete_types), because they allow incomplete types, but I don't see hashed containers there (so you'd have to use `set`).

You should be careful with storing iterators, though, because, at least for `unordered_` containers from the standard library, they may be invalidated upon
rehashing. References (and pointers) are not invalidated.

Comment: Can i use a smart pointer for this purpose? are any of the smart pointers suitable for this purpose?

Comment: You could, but it could easily end up with cyclic dependencies. If you treat your pointers as observer-only pointers then you should be fine with using them, especially since all the nodes belong to the container so their lifetime is well known.